# Xcode storyboard internal error

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode8

Here is the error:

> /Users/carson/Desktop/Not Home/Not
>   Home/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a
>   bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach all crash logs from
>   ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

And the storyboard code (its on both but this is the Launch one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11134" systemVersion="15F34" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
<dependencies>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11106"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Llm-lL-Icb"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xb3-aO-Qok"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Could you attach the relevant data from the folder noted in the error?

Comment: I solved it. See the solution below:

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply **restarting my computer**. Now it **works perfectly**.